# Add Images to an existing .xlsx or .xlsm file using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

The ruby gem that allows image insertion in an excel file is axlsx. However. it does not seem to support yet 
the ability to add an image to an existing excel file. Is anyone aware of a ruby gem that can be used for this purpose?

I am using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet%20spreadsheet) gem? Also, check out some [other spreadsheet gems at the Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting).

Comment: I do not see any support for writing images at all in spreadsheet gem.